# Where do I build my updated website?

Tags: staging, development-strategy

Where should I develop my new version of my WordPress site while my current version is live? In a subdomain of the live one? I want to work on the new site where team members can view the newest updates and where it will be easy to replace the old site with the new one once it is done.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answers! It was nice of you two to take the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you.

As a developer, I prefer working locally but if you do not develop but only add/remove/update themes and plugins, then a subdomain can be great.

This way, you can freely break your website without disturbing anyone.

Nowadays, lots of hosts providers are offering to create staging website in one click.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a subdomain, yes.

- `example.com` (old site - production)
- `new.example.com` (new site - staging)

Then when the new site is ready to go live I will just rename the sites in place and re-point DNS. I follow this general procedure:

- create DNS record `old.example.com` pointing to the old site
- add the domain `old.example.com` in hosting account for old site, and create an SSL cert for it
- log into the old site using `example.com` and update the address to `old.example.com` in *Settings > WordPress Address (URL)* and *Settings > Site Address (URL)*
- test that the old site works on `old.example.com`, and that you can log into the dashboard
- update DNS record `example.com` to point to the new site
- add the domain `example.com` in hosting account for new site, and create an SSL cert for it (this step may not be necessary if both sites are hosted in the same account)
- log into the new site using `new.example.com` and update the address to `example.com` in *Settings > WordPress Address (URL)* and *Settings > Site Address (URL)*
- test that the new site works on `example.com`, and that you can log into the dashboard